# difference between &array[0] and &array when passed to a C function

Tags: c

Is there a difference between &array[0] and &array when passed to a C Function. This array is a void* array which currently takes integer as data.

Added the test code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int read_buffer[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

int write_buffer[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

void WriteBlock(void* SrcPtr)
{
  //WriteBlock will use SrcPtr and store the data to a common memory block which ReadBlock will access.
 }

void ReadBlock(void* DstPtr)
{
   //ReadBlock function will fetch data from readBuffer and put the data back into the *DstPtr.
}

void main()
{
 WriteBlock((int*)&write_buffer);
 //Is there a difference between these two below calls.
  ReadBlock(&read_buffer[0]);
  ReadBlock(&read_buffer);
 }
```

Comment: both expressions effectively give you the same address

Comment: Which means the elements of your array are of type `void *`. Is that really what you have? How is `array` declared?

Comment: &array[0]==>void** AND &array==>void***

Comment: @OneManCrew `&array` is of type `void* (*)[how many elements in the array]`, IOW, `pointer to array of pointer to void`. Those upvoting OMC's comment, think.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - Don't be too harsh. The OP hasn't shown a line of code yet. You're making one assumption, OMC is making another. (And I'm hedging my bets...)

Comment: @Roddy The OP says `array` is an array. He also says `passed to a C function` and not `is how the function parameter is declared`. Unless there are two or more mistakes, I see no reason why I should interpret the question differently, to me it looks valid and unambiguous. Of course, we could even question whether or not `void` is `#defined` as something interesting, but I see no reason for going that far in not trusting anything stated in the question. About the only fishy thing is `takes integer as data`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - Well, IMO it's difficult to tell. I read "The array is a void * array" as "The array is a `void * array;`" The lack of a single line of code doesn't help.

Comment: yaa. I checked that. One of the function in my code which is using the pointer worked with &array but will not work with &array[0]. Within this function there is not a major difference with the way the pointer is handled. It is simple pointer handling. That's why i got confused.

Comment: @Vijay, show us the the code, please! Your questions still a bit unclear.

Comment: It is definitely possible to pass a integer pointer to function which receives void pointer. Correct me If i am wrong.

Comment: @Vijay, thanks: For the code you've posted the two calls to ReadBlock are effectively identical. But this doesn't mean that `&read_buffer[0]` is the same as `&read_buffer`.

Comment: @Roddy: Thanks. But the functionality does not work in case of &read_buffer[0]. This lead to the confusion whether &read_buffer[0] will not allow updating values to &read_buffer[1] and so on.

Comment: @Vijay - So what's the 'functionality that does not work'? what happens, and what to you *expect* to happen?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there's a big difference, and it depends on context.

Consider this:-

```
char arrayA[10];
char *arrayB;
```

`&arrayA[0]` and `&arrayB[0]` both have type `char *`.

But `&arrayA` has type `char (*)[10]` while `&arrayB` has type `char **` - the address of the  pointer.

For `arrayA`, these point to the same address - but for `arrayB`, **they do not!** There's a common C misconception that "pointers and arrays are the same". This is a great example of where they are absoluelty not,

See this : http://ideone.com/OcbuXZ

Comment: Actually, `&arrayA` has type `char (*) [10]`.

Comment: (&array[0]) + 1 != (&array) + 1 same or not ?? plz tell me... @roddy

Comment: @dev - I cant say unless you show me the code where `array` is defined. But in general, no.

Comment: `arrayB` is not an array, it's a pointer and so your example significantly differs from what's being talked about in the question.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze : Pointer/array confusion is a common beginner problem, because they're so deeply inter-related. (e.g. `void foo(char *a, char b[])`. The OP hasn't shown a line of code *yet*, so - as I said - the answer depends on the context.

Comment: yes this is not what i was checking for. You have misinterpreted the question. Please check. I have added the test-code

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `array` is declared

```
void *array[N];
```

then the expressions `&array[0]` and `&array` will yield the same *value* (the address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the array itself), but will have different *types*.

```
Expression        Type
----------        ----
    &array        void *(*)[10]  -- pointer to 10-element array of `void *`
  &array[0]       void **        -- pointer to pointer to void
```

Your function prototype will need to match up with whichever expression you pass.  If you call the function as

```
func(&array);
```

then the function prototype needs to be

```
void func(void *(*arrp)[10]) {...}
```

If you call the function as

```
func(&array[0]);
```

then the function prototype needs to be

```
void func(void **arrp) {...}
```

although in that case you should pass the size of the array as a separate parameter.

Now, assuming `array` is declared

```
void **array = malloc(sizeof *array * N);
```

then the expressions `&array` and `&array[0]` will yield different values *and* different types.

```
Expression        Type
----------        ----
    &array        void ***  
 &array[0]        void **
```

`&array` will give you the address of the `array` variable itself, which is different from the address of the heap memory that's been allocated for the array.  Again, your function prototype will need to match up with the type of the expression you use.

Comment: &array[0]      -- void ** pointer to pointer to void. It is not a pointer to pointer. It is just an pointer to int. Am i wrong

Answer (score 0):

This won't compile, you are using a `void *` and try to get the first element of it. But what size does it have? The compiler doesn't know. Using `int *` may compile, if you are not trying something like this:

```
int main (void) {
  int *arr = malloc( 10 );

  arr = &arr[0]; // this is ok
  arr = &arr;    // wrong data type
}
```

`&array` returns an `int **`, `&array[0]` returns `int *`. These are different data types.

Comment: The question is tagged C, while your code is C++ (new). How is this supposed to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

If `array` is really an array, then

- `&array[0]` is the pointer to element 0 of `array[]`
- `&array` is the pointer to the entire `array[]`

So, these two expressions are of different types. And that's the main difference that may cause your code to fail to compile if you pass the wrong one of the two.

At the low level, however, the two pointers are going to hold the same address.

Comment: pointer to the entire array points to the first(oth element) of the array only

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Have you not read the last sentence or are you suggesting to reword it?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes there is a big different**

```
&array[0]==>void**
```

**AND**

```
&array==>void***
```

Comment: Your're assuming `array` is a pointer, not an array. What if he means `void *array[10];` ?

Comment: That means that you can look at the array as a void** pointer that point to the first void* pointer in the array!