# When passing the address of the first element in an array, why write &Array[0] instead of Array?

Tags: c, arrays

In many code examples I find, they use "&Array[0]" if an array has to be passed to a function. Is there any reason to do so ? They could simply write "Array".

Comment: It is more consistent with the convention when indexing the array i.e. same as doing &array[n]. Plus often people have a hard time learning that the name of array evaluates to address of the first element.

Comment: There's no good reason and in fact I'd consider it an error.

Comment: @Dikesh Check the tags. It's C, not C++.

Comment: `&` "the address of"  `Array` "in an array" `[0]` "the first element" - you answer your own question :)

Comment: If the array was for some reason null, then it wouldn't work, but passing a null pointer would.  I think it is some kind of protection against accessing null pointers.  I've seen that sneaking into code over the years.

Comment: Additionally, i would caution you to go through http://stackoverflow.com/q/14955574/986760. Make sure you understand they are same ONLY in above situation and not in all cases. A quick example, if you pass both of these to sizeof(), result would be different. One returns size of array in bytes vs the other returns size of pointer. Hope that helps

Comment: Maybe they're just following what they 1st saw and haven't tried the array name only.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pure style issue, and you should just do whatever your dev team prefers.  Personally I like to use plain old `Array` and if I want to offset by `n` elements I would do `Array + n`.  But some people find that confusing and use `&Array[n]`, even when `n == 0`.

In defense of the other side the `Array + n` syntax requires you to know more about C in order to understand it.  It involves both arrays degenerating into pointers, and also pointer arithmetic.  But in my view, C programmers need to know all that stuff anyway, it's not a complicated language.

Comment: "But in my view, C programmers need to know all that stuff anyway" - Agreed. If you're working on a real project and don't know the semantics of arrays then you're already in a really bad spot.  Production code should not be catered to beginners.

Comment: Having programmed in C for almost a decade, (7+ years in industry) I would also argue that if i see it written that way (&arr[0]), the first thing that comes to mind is, whether it is written by some one new to C? May be they have only read the chapter on arrays and not pointers yet? I really don't recall ever seeing any good open source / professional c code which indexes the first element that way. Would love to see an example.