# getting unexpected values in my simple program in C

Tags: c

when I am compiling this small program I am getting different values as output, instead of getting numbers from `0 to 5`. And the size of array is always `8`. The different values I am getting are:

```
-981774704
32767
0
0
4195728
0
```

Any tips would be really valuable. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[10];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    int z = sizeof(&array);
    printf("\n Size of array is %d", z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are not storing anything in the array before printing. what values do you expect other then garbage??

Comment: You have not initialized the array. It is printing the garbage value.

Comment: Your program is TOO simple, the initialization of array is missing :) BTW, welcome to SO!

Comment: `int z = sizeof(&array);` returns the size of a pointer, 8 in your case.  To get the size of the array, use `int z = sizeof array;`, which is likely 40 or 80 bytes.  To get the number of elements in the array, use `int z = sizeof array/sizeof array[0];` which is 10. in this case.

Comment: `sizeof` operator to determine the size of the type and size of the object( of the result of the expression). it is not vector#size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the elements of the array are uninitialized therefore it's printing garbage value...first initialize the elements with values...you can do this...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int array[10] ;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    array[i]=i;
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
  }
  int z = sizeof(&array);
  printf("\n Size of array is %d", z);

  return 0;
}
```

if you want the array to be initialized automatically then declare the array globally...
if you want to get the size of the whole array remove &

```
sizeof(array);
```

Comment: `int z = sizeof(&array);` : remove `&` or `int z = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);` (always 10! LOL)

Comment: thanks for explaining thoroughly. I am very new to C. but thanks

Comment: here sizeof(&array); is equivalent to sizeof(array[0]);    
if you want to get the size of the whole array remove &    

    sizeof(array);

Comment: "sizeof(&array); is equivalent to sizeof(array[0]);" is at best mis-leading, at worst, it is wrong.  Given `int array[10]`: `sizeof(&array)` returns the size of a pointer, typical values area 2, 4 or 8.  `sizeof(array[0])` returns the size of an `int` whose typical sizes are 2, 4 or8.   Pointer size and `int size` are not specified as needing to be the same in C.  They may or may not have the same value.  [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955574/difference-between-array0-and-array-when-passed-to-a-c-function)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't assigning any values to the array, so you're getting the uninitialized values.
You need to do something like `array[0] = 5; //or some value` etc.

If you want an array of size 8, with the numbers indexing the array stored in it, so {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, you could do something like:

```
int array[8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    array[i] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C will not initialize your array to any default value. When you create the array it will be full of garbage values (nothing relevant or defined). Always initialize your data using memset or something equivalnet.

So if you are expecting a value of 0 on a new array then initialize it like this:

```
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
```

Comment: `int array[10] = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

you have to initialize your array first, memory may not be filled with 0 by default

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie It does answer the question. The solution is so simple, a complete answer can be written as "initialize your variables"...

Comment: @Lundin humm, you're right (in fact, I have flagged it without reading in details the question), but there were already other answers more complete before this one, so that I think this (and some others) are unnecessary there...