# what does *(&char_array) mean in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I have this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

char char_ar[] = "hello world.";
char* char_ptr = char_ar;

/*Same thing*/
printf("*Same thing:\n");
printf("%x : %c\n", &*char_ptr, *char_ptr);
printf("%x : %c\n", &*char_ar, *char_ar);

/*Not same thing*/
printf("*Not the same thing:\n");
printf("%x : %c\n", char_ptr, *char_ptr);
printf("%x : %c\n", &char_ar, *(&char_ar));

getchar();
}
```

The last printf does not print out "mem_address : h".

Instead, it prints out "mem_address : some_random_char"

What does  ***(&char_array)** in that line do so that it outputs random character?

Comment: Side note: use `%p` for pointers.

Comment: Using wrong argument type for a type specifier in a format string invokes undefined behaviour. Once invoked, you are out of the language - anything can happen.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: `6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators, 3 [...] If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue.`

Comment: so if the mem address is : 0018F824. It will print out the "24" byte which means "$". Ok got it. Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%x : %c\n", char_ptr, *char_ptr);
```

prints the character that `char_ptr` points to, which should be 'h'.

```
printf("%x : %c\n", &char_ar, *(&char_ar));
```

prints the first byte of the address of `char_ptr`, interpreted as a character, which should show up as a completely random and unpredictable character.

Answer (score 6):

`*(&char_array)` is equivalent to `char_array`. In this case `*` and `&` nullify each other's effect.

C11- §6.5.3.2/3:

> The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type "type", the result has type "pointer to type". If the operand is the result of a unary `*` operator, neither that operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue. [...]

Note that you should have use `%p` instead of `%x` for pointer data type.

Answer (score 0):

haccks is absolutely correct that `*(&char_ar)` is equivalent to `char_ar`, but I also wanted to add that `*(&char_ar)` is NOT the same as `&*char_ar`.

Add these two lines to see the difference:

```
// This is a char**
printf("%p, sizeof(&*char_ar): %d\n", &*char_ar, sizeof(&*char_ar));

// This is a char*[]
printf("%p, sizeof(*(&char_ar)): %d\n", *(&char_ar), sizeof(*(&char_ar)));
```

[See here for a additional explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14957134/942746).

Would've posted as a comment, but it would be a bit much with code examples.